# Why is safari not rendering my AngularJS bindings properly?

Tags: angularjs, safari

I've encountered an angular issue that only seems to occur in Safari:

TL;DR - Here is an obvious example of what I describe below (obviously this will only be demonstrated if you run the plunk in safari)
https://plnkr.co/edit/t6Ts2DlhV84C7CLFzdui?p=preview

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('safariBug', []);
    app.controller('main', function($scope) {
      $scope.mytext = "Here is a bunch of text, some of which will continue to be displayed.";
      $scope.update = function() {
        $scope.mytext = "New line of text.";
      }
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-app='safariBug'>
  <div ng-controller='main'>
     <div style='height:300px;width:300px;font-size:48px'>{{mytext}}</div>
     <input type='button' ng-click='update()' value='Update Text' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When displaying a string in a view using a data-bound variable, replace the string with a new value it gets displayed immediately, but if the old value is longer it doesn't get erased.  For instance if the string is "An original sentence", and its replaced with "New text", it will end up displaying something such as "New textinal sentence".  As soon as the  the style of the html element is modified, it seems to force Safari to re-render the element correctly with the old text removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style='height:300px;width:300px;font-size:48px' ng-bind="mytext"</div>
```

Try this way.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it!  Is this a bug in AngularJS, a bug in Safari, or am I just doing it incorrectly?

Comment: This is just another way of binding the data in angular and upvote would be appreciated from you.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of upvote, I didn't have enough influence points before